# How to ignore ID column in LGBMClassifier without dropping column?

Tags: python, data-science, lightgbm

I need to retain my `id` column for predictions on test data, but the model uses `id` as a predictor variable, which is not desired.  Appreciate the help!

```
x_train = train.drop(columns=['tgt'], axis=1)
y_train = train['tgt']
x_test = test_new.drop(columns=['tgt'], axis=1)
y_test = test_new['tgt']

rand = LGBMClassifier(seed=seed, learning_rate=0.1, num_leaves=12, n_estimators=700)
train_data = lgb.Dataset(x_train, label=y_train)
rand.fit(train_data)
```

Comment: try making the id column the index of the dataframe - this way it wont be used for training but you still have the information when you look at the dataframes

Answer (score 0):

Try [ignore_column](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/stable/Parameters.html#ignore_column) parameter.

```py
rand = LGBMClassifier(seed=seed, learning_rate=0.1, num_leaves=12, n_estimators=700, ignore_column="name:tgt")
train_data = lgb.Dataset(train, label=y_train, ignore_column="name:tgt")
rand.fit(train_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have the solution in your code (almost):

```
x_train = train.drop(columns=['tgt', 'id'], axis=1)
y_train = train['tgt']
x_test = test_new.drop(columns=['tgt', 'id'], axis=1)
y_test = test_new['tgt']

rand = LGBMClassifier(seed=seed, learning_rate=0.1, num_leaves=12, n_estimators=700)
train_data = lgb.Dataset(x_train, label=y_train)
rand.fit(train_data)
```